# HOW-TO Import the MaxMind GeoIP Free Country CSV file into MySQL and save diskspace

Tags: mysql

HOW-TO Import the MaxMind GeoIP Free Country CSV file into MySQL and save diskspace, anyone have SQL file?

Comment: 1. Create the database with the right fields 2. Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Navicat.  It is a GUI That allows you to easily import CSV files; look it up on google. Otherwise, you can use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` statement.